# Shortest Paths: Triangular inequality not satisfied for the Distance matrix API

Tags: matlab, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

**Initial:**

[image: 1st Screenshot from MatLab]

**After setting lat/lon precision to 30 digits:**

[image: 2nd Screenshot from MatLab - after setting lat/lon precision to 30 digits]

I am trying to find travel times from a set of GPS locations. I have downloaded node-to-node distances from the Distance matrix API.

Nevertheless, running a simple script in Matlab it seems like triangular inequality is not satisfied? (i.e. I can find a shorter path between two nodes).

For example: 
I have nodes with id: 3, 9, 2 
going from 3 to 9 and then to 2 it takes 2046 meters, whereas going from 3 to 2 directly it takes 2047 meters (these numbers are directly downloaded from the google maps API).

Did anyone have the same issue?

Comment: Why would you expect driving distances to satisfy triangular inequality?

Comment: Taking into consideration distances, triangular inequality should always be satisfied since the traveled distance between locations A-B-C is always greater (or equal) to the distance between A-C. It can be equal if in order to go to C from A you need to pass by B. It cannot be less, because if it was faster to go from A to C through B, this would have been picked up as the shortest path between A-C

Comment: The DistanceMatrix bases it's route on travel time, not only distance.

Comment: @geocodezip I know the Distance Matrix API has several outputs. Travel times would obviously not satisfy triangular inequality because each road has different velocity limits. What I mean is that it seems like the shortest path algorithm from the Distance Matrix API suffers from precision issues: In fact, I can find a shortest path between A-C by passing through B. Even though the difference between paths lengths ABC and AC might be of a few meters, this affects a lot certain applications.

Comment: Is the path from A to C through B have same travel time as that of from only A to C?

Comment: No also travel times do not correspond...

Comment: @Claudia Google distance matrix gives you the best travel time route by default but not the best distance route.

Comment: @Coder thanks for your answer. This makes sense, although I find the same issue with travel times (that is, I can find a shorter path -- in terms of time -- between AC through B). The difference is still very small...

Comment: @Claudia Can you share those A,B and C values you are using to make the comparison?

Comment: @Coder For example, try the following coordinates: A=[37.7828381556788,-122.421233129401], B=[37.7815795005554,-122.416120210932],C=[37.7807310869763,-122.415175646018]. I am now retrieving durations and I found that AC takes 411 seconds and ABC 410 seconds.

Comment: @Coder If you want to try distances instead try A=[37.7828381556788,-122.421233129401], B=[37.7815795005554,-122.416120210932], C=[37.7806901984396,-122.412767703251]. In this case I get 1211 meters vs 1210 meters

Comment: @Claudia This is the Google distance matrix call for A to C https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=37.7828381556788,-122.421233129401&destinations=37.7807310869763,-122.415175646018 which gave me duration of `410` seconds but not `411`

Comment: @Claudia This is for the second case again for A to C the distance I got is `1210` but not `1211`. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=37.7828381556788,-122.421233129401&destinations=37.7806901984396,-122.412767703251

Comment: @Coder I have added a screenshot of the function I have written in Matlab  and output for AC in my main question :)

Comment: @Coder  Ok so I found the problem for this specific case: I was setting the precision of the lats/longs too low in my function (num2str) - see fig1 in my original question...I re-run the code but now I find other problematic paths (even with a precision of 30 digits for the lats/longs). For example, take A=[37.788602890926903 -122.421067108399] B=[37.785774326702203 -122.41319560187399], C=[37.785162329514101 -122.40948750963901]. I get 1484 and 1485 meters.

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=37.788602890926903,-122.421067108399&destinations=37.785162329514101,-122.40948750963901&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=37.788602890926903,-122.421067108399&destinations=37.785774326702203,-122.41319560187399&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=37.785774326702203,-122.41319560187399&destinations=37.785162329514101,-122.40948750963901&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false

Comment: Have you noticed the 23 second difference for A to C (380 seconds) when compared to A->B->C (403 seconds 153+250). The path from A to C has shortest time and hence it is shown in the result rather that the path through B even if has less distance. I point again Google distance matrix gives the `best time` result by `default` but `not the best distance`.

Comment: @Claudia You are not observing the fact that it is giving you the best time route not the shortest path

Comment: @Coder: You're right. On the other hand, I can find counter examples for the duration. For example take locations A=[37.788357432077504 -122.410135352542] B=[37.7888544706192 -122.408541811612] C=[37.7902999151566 -122.407761002990]. I find 195 seconds ABC and 196 seconds AC

Comment: @Claudia I agree with you on this one. You can file a bug with Google for this. The only explanation I see for this will be that Google maps can't pinpoint the lat/long you gave for B and C ( cuz you can see these are ranging from 441-445 and 625-635)

Comment: @Coder Thanks for your help. You can now find the issue in the google issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36824713

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess but could it be a rounding error? Maybe the resolution of the distances you acquired is not high enough?

Comment: I retrieve distances in meters (the highest accuracy in the distance matrix API). My guess is that distances suffer from GPS error (also considering it is only 1-3 meters per kilometer, which is more or less the error you might expect for GPS traces)